# Twilio not requesting TwiML endpoint

Tags: python, twilio

I'm trying to create a call that asks me how I'm doing.  I've set up a TwiML endpoint (locally that I'm exposing with ngrok) that contains the instructions.

When I run my code, I get a phone call from/to the numbers I expect.  However, my URL is never accessed.  So the instructions are never loaded.  Instead I get a default message from twilio explaining the I'm using a trial account.

Is my code incorrect or do I need to upgrade my account?

My python code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

twilio = Client(account_id, auth_token)
twilio.calls.create(to='+123', from_='+456', url='mysite.com/call.xml')
```

`curl mysite.com/call.xml` returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Hello, how are you today?</Say>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the OP is correct.  When Twilio calls you on a demo account, it says some canned phrase and then prompts you to press any digit to continue.  Press a digit and the webhook will be sent.

If you're using a production account, this won't happen and the call will come through without the preamble.